# como obtener todos los valores de un objeto ?

Tags: javascript

```
// practica de clasess 
class Restaurante{
    constructor(menu = {}, meseros = [], horarios = [] ){
        this.menu = menu
        this.meseros = meseros
        this.horarios = horarios
    }
    verMenu(){
        let menu = this.menu
        for(let i = 0; i< menu.length; i++){
            console.log(`Plato: ${menu[i]}\n`)
        }
    }
}

const victorFood = new Restaurante()

victorFood.menu = {
    'pastas' :[
        '4 quesos',
        'primavera'
    ]
}
```

Como prodria acceder a todas las propiedades de victorFood.menu ? obteniendo un output ordenado, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un objeto de javascript esta conformado por propiedades y valores, de esta manera: `{propiedad:valor, propiedad2:valor2};`

Puedes obtener los valores de un objeto de la siguiente manera:
    `Object.values(objeto)`. Eso te devolverá un arreglo con todos los valores

Y en tu codigo puedes hacerlo asi:

```
verMenu(){
    let menu = Object.values(this.menu);
    for(let i = 0; i<menu.length ; i++){
        console.log(menu[i])
    }
}
```

Para obtener un array de todas las propiedades se hace así:

```
Object.keys(objeto);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// practica de clasess 
class Restaurante{
    constructor(menu = {}, meseros = [], horarios = [] ){
        this.menu = menu
        this.meseros = meseros
        this.horarios = horarios
    }
    verMenu(){
        let menuType = Object.keys(this.menu) //nombre de la propiedad        
        menuType.map((val, i, menuType) => {
            let nowMenu = this.menu[val]// nombre del menu en el momento de ejecucion de la funcion en map()
            console.log(`${val} \n|`)
            nowMenu.map((val, i, nowMenu)=> console.log(`----${val}`))
        })
    }
}

const victorFood = new Restaurante()

victorFood.menu = {
    'pastas' :[
        '4 quesos',
        'primavera'
    ],
    'carnes' :[
        'Lomito',
        'Parrilla'
    ]
}
victorFood.verMenu()
```

De esta manera lo logre hacer.